# Why Electron-Angular project gives the GL ERROR while build

Tags: electron, angular7

My Project is built on Angular-7 & Electron-6. The OS of my pc is Ubuntu-18.04. When I build the project it's showing the error bellow. The code snippet is bellow:

main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
let win;
function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
  });
  win.loadFile(`./dist/smartPharmacyErp/index.html`);
  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
};
app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') { app.quit() }
});
app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) { createWindow() }
});
```

The errors are:

- GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
- Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.